# Button activation

Tags: buttons, web-app

In a web app I have a grid with rows that can have an optional *property* with 3 states:

1. property is not set, no need of button C
2. property is set, button C "edit"
3. property is set, button C "view"

```
+---------+----------------+
| title   | property       |
+---------+----------------+
|row1     |                |
+--------------------------+
|row2     |                |
+--------------------------+
|row2     |                |
+--------------------------+

+-----------------------+
| A  |  B  |  C  |   D  |
+----+-----+-----+------+
```

The "C" button should appear/disappear or it should be always present but not active when *property* is not set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a UX perspective, you should have a separate button for each action. Changing the action of a button confuses the user, because they have to understand what action it will perform at that point in time.

And with a single button, they have no way of knowing that a mode is disabled.

For example, if the user wants to Edit, but the button reads *View*, they might start looking for an Edit button not knowing it's disabled. However, if a separate *Edit* button is visible but greyed out, they know it's possible to Edit, but the current state of the application doesn't allow editing.

These are described by Don Norman in the [Design of Everyday Things](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1452654123) as mode errors:

> Mode errors occur when devices have different modes of operation, and the action appropriate for one mode has different meanings in other modes.

And more specifically:

> Mode errors are especially likely where the equipment does not make the mode visible.

Comment: I can't understand from your answer if it's correct that the button can change "label" or should I try to find a unique "label" that fits every status. Thanks.

Comment: From a UX perspective, you should have a separate button for each action. Changing the action of a button confuses the user, because they have to understand what action it will perform at that point in time. And with a single button, they have no way of knowing that a mode is disabled. For example, if the user wants to Edit, but the button reads *View*, they might start looking for an Edit button not knowing it's disabled. However, if a separate *Edit* button is visible but greyed out, they know it's possible to Edit, but the current state of the application doesn't allow editing.

Comment: I've edited my answer with the above comment to be more concise :)